# Value of session is not changing

Tags: php

I'm not sure why but the value of $_SESSION['name'] is not changing even though the query is succesful. Session is started I just didn't include it in the code.

```
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $name= $_POST['name'];


    $query = "
        UPDATE users SET name = '$name'
        WHERE id = '$id';
        ";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
    }
?>
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection - should address this

Comment: You probably don't have anything coming in $_POST

Comment: how are you certain the query is succesful?

Comment: I checked the value in the database and it was successfully changed

Comment: I mean, the code... Not the database result. Did you check the value of your mysqli_query ?

Comment: Sorry about that, just an update, it seems that it is actually working but not until i refresh the page.